# Running shell script commands sequentially in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, ssh

In Jenkins, I have created a job which runs many shell script commands:

```
command1
command2
...etc
```

`command1` is an ssh command which calls a shell script file on another server machine. I have to wait until it is finished, and AFTER it, `command2` should come.

So, how can I make sure that the script file on the other machine, started by `command1`, has already finished its jobs, when in the Jenkins job the next command (`command2`) is started?

Or, alternatively,how can I make sure that `command2` won't be started until the shell script on the other machine (started by `command1`) has already finished?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out "[How to send many commands to shell and wait for the command behind ends](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63655/7490)" in order to chain commands and wait for their completion.

When you execute a command through an ssh session, you might have to wrap that command in a script able to loop/wait for the command completion.
See an example in "[How can I make ssh wait until the command exits?](https://serverfault.com/a/543550/783)".
Or (a simpler wraper): [How do I know when a command run over ssh has finished?](https://superuser.com/a/931583/141)

```
#/bin/bash
$@ 
echo "==== Command Output Finished ===="
```

> look for the string `==== Command Output Finished ====` in your I/O routines to determine where the boundary between command outputs are.
>   Or you can try isolate those commands in their own Jenkins shell build step.
>   (Not a different job, just a different build step within the same job)

Comment: 1. Actually, I have found this link that you sent, but I fear that if I run command1 which is an ssh command, which calls an .sh file on a remote machine, this command1 will return successfuly as finished on my machine, and command2 is started, while the tasks on the remote machine (started by command1 via the .sh file) are not finished,yet. It can happen, isn't it?<br>2. Does isolation mean that I should create another jenkins jobs? I would like to avoid it, if possible. Or can I start a jenkins job from another jenkins job and wait until it is finished? (Sorry, I'm new to Jenkins.)Thank you.

Comment: @Colossus I have edited the answer to address your 2 comments.

Comment: Just a question in connection with the different build step. I found it how to do, but the problem remains, isn't it? If I start the command1 in a different build step, it can happen that this command is considered as finished successfuly, but the tasks on the remote machine (started by command1 via .sh file) have not finished,yet. Or command1 is considered finished when all tasks are finished that were genereted by command1?Thank you.

Comment: @Colossus I agree, even in separate step you would still need the wrapper I mention in order to detect commmand1 has been completed.